# Cocoapod with three schemes

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a project that handles network connections. It has three schemes: Prod, Beta and Mock. I'd like to convert this into a CocoaPod that has three spec files.

How can I specify the scheme in my spec file?

Comment: you can go throgh tutorial of cocoapods http://www.raywenderlich.com/12139/

Comment: @HareshGhatala Can you be more specific please? I can't find anything on that page that touches my problem..?

Comment: @HareshGhatala this is for learing how to use CocoaPods but not to create a podfile.

Comment: @Andy here is a great tutorial for your problem: http://theonlylars.com/blog/2013/01/20/cocoapods-creating-a-pod-spec/. It also deals with the problem of defining Subspecs.

Comment: @Zero3nna Thanks - subspecs look like they could be useful, but I'm still not sure where I specify the scheme that the subspec should point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1703#issuecomment-31186237) in the CocoaPods project, and it appears that this isn't in scopre for the project right now.